# onClick event returns promise, need to call a function after resolving the promise in onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, onclick

In the below example, i want the value 'overwritten' to be displayed in div 'one', after waiting for the click event to complete. I am really missing something after triggering the click button, 'click here!'.

jsFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/RajKumari_1/qcaz9ygn/

```js
var asyncCall = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('one').innerText = "1";
      resolve('true')
    }, 500);
  })
}

var afterAsync = () => {
  document.getElementById('callAsync').click();
  document.getElementById('one').innerText = "overwritten";
}

$("#callAsync").click(asyncCall);
$("#afterAsync").click(afterAsync);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="callAsync">callAsyn</button>
<button id="afterAsync">click here !</button>

<div id="one"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to store your promise:

```js
var asyncCall = function() {
  promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('one').innerText = "1";
      console.log('1');
      resolve('true')
    }, 500);
  })
}
var afterAsync = () => {
  document.getElementById('callAsync').click();
  if(promise) {
    promise.then(()=>{
      document.getElementById('one').innerText = "overwritten";
      console.log('overwritten');
    })
  }
  
}
$("#callAsync").click(asyncCall);
$("#afterAsync").click(afterAsync);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="callAsync">
callAsyn
</button>
<button id="afterAsync">
click here ! 
</button>
<div id="one">

</div>
```